# Как объединить несколько частей бинарного файла в единый файл в C++?

Tags: c++, файлы

Всем добрый вечер!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как объединить несколько частей одного файла в единый файл? Т.е. их нужно просто поочередно слить в конечный файл. Причем эти части довольно большого размера - примерно по 1-2 гигабайта, и таких частей в среднем 5-6. Это части одного архива формата GZ.

Интересует не конкретное решение, а направление решения - в какую сторону изучать. В C++ опыта почти нет, только базовые знания, небольшие алгоритмы и т.п.

Спасибо!

Comment: Abyx, так ведь нужно не в командной строке Linux, а в C++. Так-то конечно просто.

Comment: наверное вы имеете в виду формат tar с методом сжатия .gz

Comment: Beeen007, да не имеет значения, хоть для текстовых файлов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Направление? Начнем  краю. Все файлы находятся в 1 каталоге, вызов

```
    prog_cat *
```

В программе это разбор параметров программы

```
main(argc, argv[])
```

где argc - кол-во параметров, argv - список.

Создать новый файл, куда будет записан результирующий файл, функция open с параметром O_CREAT. Далее в цикле открываем тем же open файлы из параметров по очереди для чтения. И добавляем во вновь созданный файл

```
    while ((n_read = read(входящий_файловый_дескриптор, buf, длина_буфера)) > 0) {
      if (write(результирующий_файловый_дескриптор, buf, n_read) < n_read) {
       return errno;
      }
    }
```